# Creating parent and child nodes with a treeview and duplicate strings

Tags: powershell, treeview, treenode

I am creating a GUI based script that when the user enters a username, it retrieves a comma delimited log file with information like date and time logged in, the machine they logged into, etc.
As part of the GUI I would like to use a TreeView to present them with a list of the MAC addresses that the username they entered has logged into.
In some cases there are many duplicates, for different times logged in over the course of a year.
I would like to be able to display the unique instances as parent nodes, and then for each duplicate instance, add it as a child node to the corresponding parent node along with the time they logged in.

I have what i think is part of the solution, the adding of the unique nodes, and its working as i expected, but am having quite a tough time adding the duplicate nodes as child nodes to the corresponding parent nodes.

Ex: if the user has logged into hostname COMP1, 6 times throughout the log file, I want to display COMP1 as a parent node and if the users presses the + symbol, they will see the 6 instances listed below with the date property attached.

Here is a sample from the .CSV log file, properties at the top line:

```
Date,EventType,ConnectionType,UserDomain,UserLogonTime,LogonType,HostName,HostAddress,HostStartTime,RemoteStationName,RemoteStationAddress
3/24/2015 12:49:58 PM,Logon,Local,DOMAIN,3/24/2015 12:49:13 PM,CONSOLE,F0A8F0B01660,10.10.10.11,3/24/2015 12:27:15 PM,N/A,N/A
3/26/2015 12:32:56 PM,TS Session Connected,Remote-RDP,DOMAIN,3/24/2015 7:13:19 AM,CONSOLE,VFP3077V,10.10.10.10,3/23/2015 6:56:32 AM,Dingus,10.10.96.72
```

The properties I'm selecting from the log file are hostname and date.

Here is some of my current code:

```
$array = Import-Csv $filepath\$username.txt | Where-Object {$_.EventType -eq  "TS   Session Connected" -or $_.EventType -eq "Logon"} | select -ExpandProperty     hostname | sort -Unique

$array2 = Import-Csv $filepath\$username.txt | Where-Object {$_.EventType -eq "TS Session Connected" -or $_.EventType -eq "Logon"} | select -ExpandProperty Date | sort -Unique

#Loops through and singles out each host name, and adds it as a treenode 
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Count; $i++) {
$node = $treeviewHostnames.Nodes.Add($array[$i]) | Out-Null
}
```

The treeview object:

```
$treeviewHostnames = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$treeviewHostnames.size = New-Object drawing.Size @(300,378)
$treeviewHostnames.Location = New-Object drawing.Size @(380,165)
$treeviewHostnames.Scrollable = $true
```

This adds a unique list of hostnames to my treeview object but I'm having a tough time adding the specific duplicate child hostnames to the unique parent hostnames.

Comment: Do you by chance have a sample data set for use so we don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Updated original post, completely forgot to include data from the log, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved thanks to Dan at [Powershell.org](http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/creating-parent-and-child-nodes-with-a-treeview-and-duplicate-strings/)

His example .CSV:

```
HostName,LastLogon
COMP1,032820151913
COMP1,032720151913
COMP2,032820151913
COMP2,032720151913
```

His code:

```
    function Add-Node { 
    param 
    ( 
        $RootNode, 
        $HostName,
        $LastLogon
    )

    $newNode = new-object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
    $newNode.Name = "$HostName -- $LastLogon"
    $newNode.Text = "$HostName -- $LastLogon" 

    If(($RootNode.Nodes | Foreach-Object {$_.Tag}) -contains $HostName)
    {
        $HostNode = $RootNode.Nodes | ?{$_.Tag -eq $HostName}
    }
    Else
    {
        $newHostNode = new-object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
        $newHostNode.Name = $HostName
        $newHostNode.Text = $HostName
        $newHostNode.Tag = $HostName

        $Null = $RootNode.Nodes.Add($newHostNode)
        $HostNode = $RootNode.Nodes | ?{$_.Tag -eq $HostName}
    }

    $Null = $HostNode.Nodes.Add($newNode)
    }

    $Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Text = "TreeView"

    $TreeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 224
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 200
    $TreeView.Size = $System_Drawing_Size

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 13
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 37
    $TreeView.Location = $System_Drawing_Point

    $Form.Controls.Add($TreeView)

    $TreeNode = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode -ArgumentList 'Computers'
    $TreeNode.Tag = 'Computers'

    $CSV = Import-CSV .\LogonInfo.txt

    Foreach($Computer in $CSV)
    {
Add-Node -RootNode $TreeNode -HostName $Computer.HostName -LastLogon $Computer.LastLogon
    }

    $Null = $TreeView.Nodes.Add($TreeNode)

    $TreeView.ExpandAll()
    $Form.ShowDialog()
```

His explanation:
What this script does is basically
1. Setup a simple form to display the TreeNode in a TreeView
2. Add a root TreeNode tagged Computers, we will add all computers to this TreeNode
3. Import the CSV file
4. Loop through the CSV and add a node foreach computer in the CSV. The Add-Node function checks if a childnode with a tag which equals the hostname of the computer is present, if it is, we simply add the logon information to that node. If it isn't, we create a new childnode using the hostname of the computer. Next, we select that newly created node to add the logon information.
5. Last, the script expands all nodes and displays the form.

Hope this is helpful.

Thankful to Dan for his help!